# Get data from URL PHP

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I want to have a system that looks for a page at that URL and if it cant find one it passes the URL to the last page it can find (sorry for the bad explanation, this is the only way I could think of putting it). Example: say I entered the URL "www.mysite.com/users/username" it would pass the string "username" to "users.php" instead of having it like www.mysite.com/users?user=username. if there is no users.php in the site then it directs you to a 404 page.

Sorry for the really bad explanation all I really need is a name of what this would be called and I could find some information on it but I am not sure what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you using Apache, IIS or other webserver?

Comment: This is generally done using rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below rules in .htaccess file in your project's root folder

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yoursite.com/404.php
```

And include the below code in users.php and 404.php will give you a solution

```
$request = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = $request["path"];
$result = explode('/',rtrim($path,'/'));
echo $result[2];
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to add that to all PHP files I wanted to have as a page you could pass data in this way to? Is there any way I can forward all URLs to the index.php file for all processing and then having it display the right page?

Answer (score 0):

Try php codeigniter framework your problem will get solved, it is codeigniter default functionality.